sudden issues with monitors and sleep mode with 6.5.0-28-generic kernel
I have Kubuntu 22.04 and KDE 5.24.7 on my desktop. On 4/19/24 it downloaded and installed kernel 6.5.0-28-generic. After this, I suddenly had 2 issues:

I have 2 monitors. One of the monitors would not turn on while in the KDE desktop. However, while booting and also after getting into KDE and pressing CTRL-ALT-F2 to switch to the terminal the monitor worked, so I knew there wasn't a hardware problem with the monitor.
I could no longer put the computer into sleep mode. When I clicked on "sleep", it appeared to go into sleep mode (the working monitor would turn off), but the CPU fan never turned off and it was still "awake".

I was able to revert back to 6.5.0-27-generic from the grub menu and the above issues went away, but they are concerning. Are these known issues?
Is there a way I can tell it to keep 6.5.0-27-generic while waiting on a fix for these issues?
UPDATE
Info from /var/log/apt/history.log:
Start-Date: 2024-04-19 19:39:32
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-28-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1, automatic), linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-28:amd64 (6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-6.5.0-28-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1, automatic), linux-image-6.5.0-28-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.27.28~22.04.1, 6.5.0.28.29~22.04.1), linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.27.28~22.04.1, 6.5.0.28.29~22.04.1), linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.27.28~22.04.1, 6.5.0.28.29~22.04.1)
End-Date: 2024-04-19 19:40:36

They are "known issues" if you or someone else filed bug reports. The previous kernel is always kept by default.

Does this answer your question? How to prevent updating of a specific package?

@karel That might do it, but I don't know if locking 6.5.0-28-generic itself will also lock the associated packages (linux-image-6.5.0-28-generic:amd64, etc.) or if I need to lock all of them.

Putting the kernel package on hold will prevent you from updating the kernel package, but it will not prevent you from updating other installed packages.
